# Is it possible in seagull load generator to send the the avp2 or avp3 in diameter response which is dependent on the value of avp1 in request?

Tags: diameter-protocol

I want to send the value of server-name avp which depends whether the public-id avp was received in previous UAR request. If public-id was received in previous request then I have to send the same value in user-name avp else a new grouped avp (server-capabilities which contains multiple mandatory and optional capability avps)  has to be sent in the UAA.

I am aware that seagull has capabilty to store the avp value and then restore the same value in another avp for subsequent request and response. But I have doubt on how to simulate such conditional scenarios as mentioned above.

Any pointer is greately appreciated!

I could store the value of server-name avp and then restore in user-name avp.
Couldn't find a way to conditionally send the server-capabilities grouped avp.